# Update mongo document filtered by parent and nested Id using C# driver

Tags: c#, mongodb

First, sorry for my english ;)

I have the next classes that represents a person which can have many email accounts and each of those accounts have its respective email messages

```
public class Person
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public EmailAccount[] Accounts { get; set; }
}

public class EmailAccount
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Message[] Messages { get; set; }
}

public class Message
{
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

I need to replace the messages of particular email account, but i need first do a select by person id and account id, how can i do this with Mongodb c# driver, I made something like this but without success:

```
var collection = _mongoDatabase.GetCollection<Person>("Person");
var query = Query.EQ("Person._id", "20");

var bsonMessages = BsonDocumentWrapper.CreateMultiple(new[]
{
    new Message(DateTime.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), "Test 55"),
    new Message(DateTime.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), "Test 66")
});

var messageArray = new BsonArray(bsonMessages);

var update = Update.Set("Accounts.$.Messages", messageArray);
collection.Update(query, update, UpdateFlags.Upsert);
```

As you can see, I do the filter the person by its Id but I don't know how to add the second filter to select an account by its Id

I appreciate any help ;)